# Server 2012R2 Foundation with 2019 Standard

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain, licensing, windows-server-2019, compliance

We have done a FSMO migration from a Server 2012R2 Foundation to Server 2019 Standard.
After uninstalling the ADDS from the foundation server we started having a licensing issue with this popup:

"The server did not finish checking the license compliance. If the server is joined to a domain, make sure that the server can connect to a domain controller. If the license compliant check cannot be completed, the server will automatically shut down in 0 hour(s) 30 minute(s)."

and apparently its because of the foundation server licensing requirements.
The Foundation server needs to still be up and running, it has some SQL and FS services on it.
Is making the foundation server to a secondary dc (ie, simply re-adding it to the domain) without really using it comply with the licensing requirements?

the configuration will come out:
Server 2019 Standard - DC |
Server 2012R2 Foundation - Secondary DC

Is this gonna work?